# Is it possible to create a Command that will send Stored Data of Warns/Mutes/Bans that an User has?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

What I am trying to do is basically create a Command so it will send an Embed/Message of Stored Data from a SQLite Database. The Data that will have been stored in there will basically be Data from a possible Warn. It will show the User, Moderator, Reason and Datetime of that Warn. I just need to know how can I get that Data and put it Correctly in that Embed.

This is how I think it must work:

1. It will search for Data in the Database, if there is no Data in the DB, it will send an error Message otherwise it will continue the Proccess.
2. If Data does exist, it must find a way to send that Data in a **specific** row by using either the Datetime or maybe a Case Number which could be added in the DB. (Here it get 's a little tricky because I've already tried using number's for Cases but I had not idea how to really deal with it.)
3. After finding a way to get that Data in a specific row it must get the Data needed and put it inside of the Embed or Message.
4. Then it will just send the Embed/Message.

Seems a lot easy but I have no Idea how to start and I was looking for a bit help!

Comment: It is alright when someone Down Votes my questions, but at least tell me the reason why so next time I can avoid it...

Comment: Your question is too broad and doesn't show enough research effort. Your question should be: Unable to store user log data properly in tables after you have created a database and are stuck in creating the table. I would say this isn't the place to ask for ideas, rather the place to discuss what is wrong with your idea.

Comment: So in any case I have a problem getting Ideas, where should I go? Is there any place for that? I mean as a new Developer I sometimes need to get some help of how something will work. If StackOverflow is not that place, where should I ask?

Comment: I would recommend the [python discord](https://pythondiscord.com/) community for discussing ideas and learning python.

Comment: Oh I see, I will try asking there then for any Ideas I have! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I use MongoDB but the same principles apply. I have 1 table per function so this would be under the `user_data` table/collection for example.

```py
{
    "user_id": member.id,
    "guild_id": guild.id,
    "mod_logs": [],
}
```

I have `user_id` and `guild_id` which would be varchar 255 or any other data type. I store the mod_logs of each user in a list of dictionaries.

You would get the `mod_logs` variable into `logs` and do

```py
logs.append({"type": "WARNED", "warn_id": warn_id, "reason": reason, "issuer": ctx.author.id, "time": time_warned.strftime('%c')})
```

Comment: If you are using `sqlite` your `mod_logs` should be a json data type, not a list/array.

Comment: So Basically I will have to make a table per function? Also would I need to use MongoDB for such a thing, or using SQLite will be okay for this to work?

Comment: Either one will work @xXSkillexZ basically a table for example levels, economy, global user profiles, moderation and so on just so one change on a table doesn't affect them all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch user data and each case efficiently, I would recommend using a single table with the following columns in sqlite.

```
case_id - primary key(int) - I suggest using auto increment
type - mod action or infraction - varchar
reason - reason for infraction - varchar
user - bigint - id of the user
mod_user - bigint - id of the mod
guild = bigint - id of the guild
```

Getting the data of the user

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user={user_id};
```

Note:
This is not a question I would usually answer and this is more of a suggestion rather than an answer, which is not something you would find on stackoverflow, that is meant to be like an encyclopedia, rather than a forum for ideas.

Comment: Yeah about the Note someone explained me how StackOverflow works. Sorry for my question! Also thanks for the Answer!